# Update in View control doesn't effects the final view in open3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, open3d, visualizer

I have this toy example where i want to change the default view while calling the visualizer.run(), for example i want to change the default values of zoom , rotate and scale of the scene in the visualizer. Any help will be appreciated

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

# cloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
ply_point_cloud = o3d.data.PLYPointCloud()

pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(ply_point_cloud.path)

visualizer = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
visualizer.create_window()
visualizer.add_geometry(pcd)
view_ctl = visualizer.get_view_control()
# view_ctl=  view_ctl.convert_to_pinhole_camera_parameters()  # noqa: E501
view_ctl.scale(0)
visualizer.update_renderer()
visualizer.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine (tested and results below) however, I am pretty sure you are using version 0.17.0. Move to version `0.18.0` or more recent developer releases where this bug has been fixed. Install from [here](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/getting_started.html#development-version-pip).

P.S. Root issue is due to `get_view_control` returning a copy of `ViewControl` of `Visualizer` and hence any changes to it does not affect the `Visualizer`.

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

points = np.random.rand(30000, 3) * [1,2,3]
colors = np.random.rand(30000, 3)
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)


visualizer = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
visualizer.create_window()
visualizer.add_geometry(pcd)
view_ctl = visualizer.get_view_control()
view_ctl.camera_local_translate(forward=0, right=0.5, up=0)
visualizer.update_renderer()
visualizer.run()
```

This produces a left shifted image instead of keeping pointcloud in center - [image: shifted pointcloud due to camera moving to right]

Comment: Many thanks @saurabheights for pointing out the issue in the open3d version, after updating it, it did showed changes as you have shown in your demo