# python, Open3D: Is there a way to set parameters of vizualization without closing the window?

Tags: python-3.x, open3d, 3dcamera

I have successive `pointcloud-data` coming frame by frame from my time-of-flight camera, and I want to display it with Python 3.10, and the `open3d` library.

The goal is to show the incoming data as a live preview of the camera. This works well with the manufacturer py-script which uses the `asyncio`-library as the frames are awaitables.

However, my problem is the following:

This script uses the `o3d.visualization.Visualizer.add_geometry(pcd,True)` command from the o3d library after creating a window. I can use my mouse in the window to adjust the view and use ctrl+c to copy the current view status into the clipboard. Using the mouse every time to set the view status is cumbersome as there will always be differences in the views I get. I would like to get the same view status every time I open the window to get comparable results.

So, does anyone know how to set the view status after the `o3d.visualization.Visualizer.add_geometry(pcd,True)` has been started?

pcd ...  my point cloud data

as shown in the [open3d doc](https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/visualization/visualization.html) the view status can be copied which yields in my case:

```
{
    "class_name" : "ViewTrajectory",
    "interval" : 29,
    "is_loop" : false,
    "trajectory" : 
    [
        {
            "boundingbox_max" : [ 2.4493699073791504, 1.9389574527740479, 2.1757895946502686 ],
            "boundingbox_min" : [ -2.5847299098968506, -1.8458751440048218, 0.0 ],
            "field_of_view" : 60.0,
            "front" : [ 0.16044233442547645, 0.064093449935902075, -0.9849620738888466 ],
            "lookat" : [ 0.14832833824513739, -0.30275783432427361, 1.1003512211054685 ],
            "up" : [ 0.0019829908400814389, -0.99790843426770126, -0.064612882343332012 ],
            "zoom" : 0.29999999999999993
        }
    ],
    "version_major" : 1,
    "version_minor" : 0
}
```

Now I can use this information to display the `pointcloud` with the command `o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([ pcd], zoom=0.29999999999999993, front=[ 0.16044233442547645, 0.064093449935902075, -0.9849620738888466 ], ... , height=1080)`. This works fine.

But this is the command "o3d.visualization.**draw_geometries**" and not "o3d.visualization.Visualizer.**add_geometry**" as before.

So does anyone know if such view status arguments can also be handed to the latter command or how to update the view after the pointcloud was loaded with .add_geometry ?

I came across `o3d.visualization.Visualizer.get_view_control` and `o3d.visualization.Visualizer.update_renderer` but didn't know how to use them.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Open3d tutorial on [Non-Blocking Visualization](https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/visualization/non_blocking_visualization.html#review-draw-geometries). `update_renderer` is usually called when you are done adding/removing/updating various geometries. This is supposed to be done for each frame, like updating the screen after you are done drawing the current frame in a game.

**Next, the `update_geometries` method is just a wrapper function built on top of the `Visualizer` class.** `Visualizer` stores its view options in an object of `ViewControl` class. Changing this `visualizer.get_view_control()` fields will reflect in your Visualizer window.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77506153/1874627 if you are using Open3D version 0.17.0.

Now to set fields such as `lookat`, `front`, etc. try:-

```
vis.get_view_control().set_front(front)
vis.get_view_control().set_lookat(lookat)
vis.get_view_control().set_up(up)
vis.get_view_control().set_zoom(zoom)
```

See documentation of `ViewControl` here - https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.visualization.ViewControl.html

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77506153/1874627 which shows an example usage of `vis.get_render_option()` which allows changing rendering attributes instead of changing camera view attributes.

Comment: P.S. I have posted quite a few answers on Open3d in last 6 months, you might find helpful solutions there related to general visualization issues.

Comment: Thanks @saurabheights for the quick reaction to my question. Actually after scrolling through your answers to other questions I think the root of my problem could be the known issue with the `vis.get_view_control()` returning a copy of the view control and not effecting the view control directly (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77667668/update-in-view-control-doesnt-effects-the-final-view-in-open3d/77668375#77668375). Unfortunately the suggested set_front, ... , set_zoom have  not worked for me. Even after updating to o3d v0.18.0 it didn't work...  using v 0.16.0 it works once..

Comment: @av_bb - It seems to be a new issue. See this related issue - https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/6617

Comment: thanks again @saurabheights for your swift response. I came across your linked issue on git but became uncertain as you stated there that it might be solved with updating...   however for me it remains an open quetion how to solve it. Looking forward for an upcoming bug-fix. Thanks again and have a nice week! AV